# Raspberry pi make error cannot find -lbcm_host

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, raspberry-pi3

```
/usr/bin/Id: cannot find -Ibcm_host
collect2: error: Id returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/sdl-renderer.dir/build.make:91: recipe for target 'bin/sdl-renderer' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/sdl-renderer] Error 1
CmakeFiles/Makefile2:277: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sdl-renderer.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CmakeFiles/sdl-renderer.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What to do with it?
cmake version 3.13.3
os: debian/retropie

Comment: It seems that your have mistakenly replaced `l` (ell) with `I` (upper-case i). It should be `/usr/bin/ld` which causes the error, and `bcm_host` followed by `-l` flag. Please, paste the **actual error message**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The reason this error happened is that they were likely transcribing their error message, which happened on the Pi, to stackoverflow, which was not on the Pi. Give him some slack.